# Best practice to design an application that needs a BackgroundAgent using MVVM pattern

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, windows-phone-8, caliburn.micro

While the title may seem too broad, I actually have not found any hint on how to solve this problem.

---

EDIT:
While I tagged the question properly, I forgot to write that I'm using **Caliburn.Micro** and this means that I ***must*** have both *Views* and *ViewModels* in the same project, and this forces me to have a separate library project for the *Model*, as the *Background Agent* can't depend on the app's project

---

Before diving into the question, here's a little example of the situation:

```
- App Solution
\- Model (C# library)
\- Background agent
\- Real App
  \- Views
  \- ViewModels
  \- Resources and other stuff
```

where *Real App* and *Background Agent* depend on *Model*.

This seems to me the easiest way to make things work in my scenario.

The problem comes when I need to work with binding. In my previous projects I used to merge the *Model* and the *ViewModel* classes into one so that I could just bind the XAML to the *VIewModel*'s properties without any kind of problem.

But now, since I'm forced to keep my *Model* in a separate project (the *Background Agent* can't depend on *Real App*), I have no idea on how this should work.

To make things more complex, my *Model* uses the **async** pattern to load data.

And this leads to the first question: since the *Model* loads data using th **async** pattern, how can I notify to the *ViewModel* that the data is ready to be displayed?

To make the question clearer, here's a quick snippet about this question:

```
namespace Models
{
    public class Model
    {
        private string _neededProperty;
        public string NeededProperty
        {
            get
            {
                return _neededProperty;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value == _neededProperty) return;
                _neededProperty = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public Model()
        {
            LoadData();
        }

        private async void LoadData()
        {
            NeededProperty = await StuffLoader();
        }

        private Task<string> StuffLoader()
        {
            return LoadStringAsync();
        }
    }
}

namespace ViewModels
{
    public class ViewModel
    {       
        public string NeededProperty
        {
            get
            {
                // Let's assume that we have a global instance of our model defined in the App.xaml.cs file
                return App.Model.NeededProperty;
            }
        }
    }
}

// Page.xaml
...
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding NeededProperty, Source={StaticResource ViewModel}}"/>
...
```

How can I be sure that the `TextBlock` loads fine once the *Model* has loaded the string?

Of course the same problem needs to be solved to make the *Background Agent* work, because it relies on the same loading methods of the *Model*.

So, basically, the question is: provided that my structure is correct and that this is the best way to organize the project, how can I "listen" on *Model*'s properties to report each change to the *ViewModel* and the *Background Agent*?

This could be also useful to show some kind of loading screen, which has to be shown in the *Real App* part and so I need to know when the *Model* actually finishes its loading routines.

I hope that the question is clear, I'm a little bit confused now because this requires a big paradigm shift when coming from Java!

Comment: If `Model` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, your view should update automatically when the model property changes. That's the whole point.

Comment: That's how it works if the view is bound to the `Model`, but I have another layer between them (the `ViewModel`) so that the view is bound to `ViewModel.NeededProperty` and `ViewModel.NeededProperty` returns `Model.NeededProperty`. Are you sure that firing the `PropertyChanged○6 event on `Model.NeededProperty` will update `ViewModel.NeededProperty` ?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to wrap the model up behind the viewmodel. Just expose an instance (or collection) of your model and bind directly to that. The project that contains your viewmodel can reference the project that contains your model, and the project with the view can reference both projects.

Comment: While I tagged the question properly, I forgot to write that I'm using `Caliburn.Micro`, which requires a `ViewModel` for each `View` and they must be in the same project. This means that the `ViewModel` must be in the app's project and so I need the `Model` in a separate one as the `Background Agent` can't depend on the app itself

Comment: The location of the viewmodel doesn't change my second comment. There's no reason to hide the model's property behind a viewmodel property.

Comment: The `ViewModel` is **required** by `Caliburn.Micro`, is not something that I can choose. `Caliburn.Micro` automatically binds each property of `Page1View.xaml` to what's inside `Page1ViewModel.cs` so I actually need them if I want to have all the benefits that are coming free with this framework

Answer (score 0):

ViewModel should not be in the same project as Views.
That way you can re-use Model and ViewModel in a different App if needed (ex: desktop and phone app).
Therefore, I would use your background agent in the viewmodel (maybe through the model depending on what your are doing exactly). That way the background agent is not known from the app and your app is using your ViewModel the same way as with or without the ViewModel

IMO that is the cleanest and easiest way.

Comment: If I got it right, `Caliburn.Micro` needs to have the Views and the ViewModels in the same project to let its "naming convention" system work. That's why I put them in my _Real App_ project

Comment: I have no knowledge of Caliburn.Micro but that seems strange to me because IMO it is not the good way to use MVVM (View is created by design team while model and viewmodel is created by dev team and tested independently). One way to do this I guess is to create an event in your model that your viewmodel will register to. When your background agent updates your model, you fire your event so that the viewmodel updates accordingly (sort of binding viewmodel to model).